# Syntax Error while running an install.sh file

Tags: syntax

I have a problem with a .sh file. This file will install a. Py file in the same folder! The file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash/  
python install.py "$ @"
```

Can somebody pleace help me?

Comment: You need to put `./install.py` instead of install.py - this means it will look for `install.py` in its current directory.

Comment: Also you should remove last '/' sign. And for which aims do you give "$ @" string to install.py script?